# Vue3 composition API and pinia | submit data then reload the data

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, pinia

I'm learning Vue 3 composition API and Pinia. I'm making a todo.
When I submit a todo data through Pinia, I can submit to the DB, but it won't re-render until reload the page.
Do I need to use 'watch' to watch the state todos:[] and execute fetchTodos()?
any good solution?
here both codes, hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

----- VUE -----

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { storeToRefs } = from 'pinia'
import { useTodoStore } from '../store/todo'

const store = useTodoStore()
const { getTodos } = storeToRefs(store)

onMounted(() => {
    store.fetchTodos()
})

const todo = ref('')

const initForm = () => {
    todo.value = ''
}

// submit via Pinia
const onSubmitToPinia = () => {
  const payload = {
    todo: todo.value,
  }
  store.addTodoFromPinia(payload)
  initForm()
  store.fetchTodo()
}
</script>
<template>
<h4>TODO</h4>

  <!-- form addTodo -->
  <form class="row g-4">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <input
        class="form-control"
        v-model="newName"
        type="text"
        placeholder="todo">
    </div>
    <div>
      <button 
        class="btn btn-primary" 
        type="button"
        @click="onSubmitToPinia(payload)">
        submit through pinia</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <!-- render data from pinia -->    
  <div class="todo"
    v-for="getTodo in getTodoss.todo" 
    :key="getTodo.id">
    <b class="ms-2">{{ getTodo.todo }}</b>
  </div>
</template>
```

---- PINIA ----

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from "axios"

export const useAboutStore = defineStore('todo',{
   state: () => {
     return {
      todos: []
     }
  },
  getters: {
    getTodos(state) {
      return state.todos
    }
  },
  
  actions: {
    async fetchTodos() {
      try {
        const data = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/todo')
        this.todos = data.data
      }
      catch (error) {
        alert(error)
        console.log(error)
      }
    },
    addTodoFromPinia(payload) {
        const path = 'http://localhost:5000/todo'
        axios.post(path, payload)
      }
  },
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `storeToRefs` to accomplish what you want nor do you need to watch the state of the store.

```html
<template>
   <div class="todo"
    v-for="getTodo in store.todos" 
    :key="getTodo.id">
    <b class="ms-2">{{ getTodo.todo }}</b>
  </div>
</template>
```

If for any reason the vue complains that the array is empty put a v-if checking if the store.todos.length is != 0.
And also fix your typos.

If the problem persists show me your new code and I help you again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Luigi. Also sorry for my typos. It works!!! I shouldn't use the data array from the getters, directly from the state. No needed storeToRefs.  Thanks again